# Python - Contar o número de incidências de um evento numa janela de tempo

Tags: python, pandas

Tenho uma tabela com basicamente nomes, datas e grupos do tipo:

| Índice | Nome | Data | Grupo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | José | 01/01/2020 | A |
| 2 | José | 01/01/2020 | B |
| 3 | José | 03/02/2020 | A |
| 4 | José | 01/03/2020 | A |
| 5 | José | 01/05/2020 | A |
| 6 | Maria | 02/02/2020 | B |

Quero criar mais duas colunas nessa tabela, uma que conte quantas vezes aquele nome apareceu nos últimos 3 meses, e outra contando quantas vezes aquele nome apareceu no grupo A nos últimos 3 meses (sem contar a própria linha analisada). Ou seja:

| Índice | Nome | Data | Grupo | 90 dias qlqr evento | 90 dias evento A |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | José | 01/01/2020 | A | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | José | 01/01/2020 | B | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | José | 03/02/2020 | A | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | José | 01/03/2020 | A | 3 | 2 |
| 5 | José | 01/05/2020 | A | 2 | 2 |
| 6 | Maria | 02/02/2020 | B | 0 | 0 |

Alguém tem alguma ideia?
Eu tentei usar o groupby algumas vezes, e algo estranho aconteceu. Exemplo:

```
ds2 = ds1.groupby('Nome')
```

E o resultado gerado foi
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A descrição abaixo mostra como fazer para qualquer grupo. Vamos por partes:

### Preparando a base

#### Importando bibliotecas

```
import pandas as pd
import random
```

#### Criando o DataFrame

```
dias = 365

dti = pd.date_range("2019-01-01", periods=dias, freq="D")

names = ["José", "Maria", "João", "Teresa"]

df = pd.DataFrame({"nome": [random.choice(names) for _ in range(dias)], "data": dti})
```

Dados em df

```
       nome       data
0      José 2019-01-01
1      José 2019-01-02
2    Teresa 2019-01-03
3      José 2019-01-04
4      José 2019-01-05
..      ...        ...
360    José 2019-12-27
361    José 2019-12-28
362    João 2019-12-29
363  Teresa 2019-12-30
364    José 2019-12-31

[365 rows x 2 columns]
```

#### Criando coluna para auxiliar a contagem

```
df["dummy"] = 1
```

#### Fazendo a contagem

```
def f(x, t):
    return x.apply(lambda y: x.loc[x['data'].between(y['data'] - t, y['data'], inclusive=False), 'dummy'].sum(), axis=1)


df['30 dias'] = df.groupby('nome', group_keys=False).apply(f, pd.Timedelta(30, unit='d'))
df['90 dias'] = df.groupby('nome', group_keys=False).apply(f, pd.Timedelta(90, unit='d'))
```

o Dataframe será algo como:

```
       nome       data  dummy  30 dias  90 dias
0      José 2019-01-01      1        0        0
1      José 2019-01-02      1        1        1
2    Teresa 2019-01-03      1        0        0
3      José 2019-01-04      1        2        2
4      José 2019-01-05      1        3        3
..      ...        ...    ...      ...      ...
360    José 2019-12-27      1        6       24
361    José 2019-12-28      1        7       25
362    João 2019-12-29      1        8       21
363  Teresa 2019-12-30      1        7       22
364    José 2019-12-31      1        8       25

[365 rows x 5 columns]
```

#### Apagar coluna dummy (Opicional)

```
del df["dummy"]
```

#### Verificando

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['nome'] == 'Teresa':
        print(f'{row["data"]} => {row["30 dias"]} => {row["90 dias"]}')
```

O output será algo como:

```
2019-01-03 00:00:00 => 0 => 0
2019-01-14 00:00:00 => 1 => 1
2019-01-21 00:00:00 => 2 => 2
2019-01-24 00:00:00 => 3 => 3
2019-01-25 00:00:00 => 4 => 4
2019-01-31 00:00:00 => 5 => 5
2019-02-01 00:00:00 => 6 => 6
2019-02-03 00:00:00 => 6 => 7    <----- MUDANÇA DE MÊS
2019-02-04 00:00:00 => 7 => 8
2019-02-16 00:00:00 => 7 => 9
2019-03-01 00:00:00 => 5 => 10   <----- MUDANÇA DE MÊS
(...)
```

**Update**

Caso tenha uma coluna com o grupo

```
>>> def f(x, t, g):
...     return x.apply(lambda y: x.loc[(x['data'].between(y['data'] - t, y['data'], inclusive=False)) & (y['grupo'] == g), 'dummy'].sum(), axis=1)
...
>>> df['90 dias A'] = df.groupby('nome', group_keys=False).apply(f, pd.Timedelta(90, unit='d'), "A")
```

Espero que ajude